# Bootstrap different container width mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible with bootstrap to have a different width on mobile then on desktop? My desktop page has a full width of 80% (10% both sides) But on mobile i just want the full width. Here is an example, on desktop it looks like this: [image]

But on mobile/tablet is looks like this: [image]

Is it possible on bootstrap to have the mobile version in full width but the desktop like it is in the picture? Here is a JSfiddle  jsfiddle.net/p9nu7r63

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Servicepunt Detailhandel Groningen | Home</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon/favicon.png" type="image/png">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/jssor.slider-21.1.6.mini.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- NAVIGATIE BALK -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!-- logo -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <!--  -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
    <!-- <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 50px; height: 60px;"> -->
  </a>

  <!-- Inklappbaar ding als je op mobiel zit-->
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- menu eitems  linker kant-->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainnavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/Over/index.php">Over</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/Nieuws/index.php">Nieuws</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/Contact/index.php">Contact</a></li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <!--
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profiel <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Profiel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Instellingen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    -->
    <!-- <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised">Niet beschikbaar</button></li> -->
  </ul>

</div>
  <!-- Aan de rechterkant -->


</nav>

<!-- EINDE NAVIAGTIE BALK-->

<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
<!-- Loading Screen -->
<div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div data-p="225.00">
        <img data-u="image" src="images/red.jpg" />
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; width: 1000px; height: 120px; font-size: 50px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 60px; font-family:Open Sans;">Welkom bij Servicepunt Detailhandel Groningen</div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 30px; width: 480px; height: 120px; font-size: 30px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 38px;">Hier kom dan allemaal tekst, een kleine samenvatting van het bedrijf</div>
        <!-- <div data-u="caption" data-t="0" style="position: absolute; top: 120px; left: 650px; width: 470px; height: 220px;">
            <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 470px; height: 220px;" src="img/c-phone-horizontal.png" />
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 45px; width: 379px; height: 213px; overflow: hidden;">
                <img data-u="caption" data-t="1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 379px; height: 213px;" src="img/c-slide-1.jpg" />
                <img data-u="caption" data-t="2" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 379px; width: 379px; height: 213px;" src="img/c-slide-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <img style="position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 45px; width: 379px; height: 213px;" src="img/c-navigator-horizontal.png" />
            <img data-u="caption" data-t="3" style="position: absolute; top: 740px; left: 1600px; width: 257px; height: 300px;" src="img/c-finger-pointing.png" />
        </div> -->
    </div>
    <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
        <img data-u="image" src="images/purple.jpg" />
    </div>
    <a data-u="any" href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Full Width Slider</a>
    <div data-p="225.00" data-po="80% 55%" style="display: none;">
        <img data-u="image" src="images/blue.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
        <img data-u="image" src="images/green.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Bullet Navigator -->
<div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="bottom:16px;right:16px;" data-autocenter="1">
    <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
    <div data-u="prototype" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></div>
</div>
<!-- Arrow Navigator -->
<span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora22l" style="top:0px;left:8px;width:40px;height:58px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
<span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora22r" style="top:0px;right:8px;width:40px;height:58px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
</div>

<div class="header">
<h1>home</h1>
</div>

<div class="" id="footer">
footer
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
font-family: "Verdana";
resize: none;
width: 400px;
height: 50px;
}

label {
font-weight: normal;
}
input {
font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
margin: 0;
}

body {
background-color: grey;
}

.container-fluid {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 20px;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 0;
border: none;
font-size: 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -2px #5b5b5b;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -2px #5b5b5b;
         box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -2px #5b5b5b;
}

.navbar-header{
right: auto;
}

.navbar-nav > li{
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
border-color: none;
}

.icon-bar {
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;

}

.navbar-collapse {
border: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
border-color: transparent;
box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: blue;
}

#footer {
padding: 20px;
width: auto;
height: 400px;
background-color: #efefef;
}

.header {
 background-color: lightgrey;
 width: auto;
 height: 660px;
}

/* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 05 css */
/*
.jssorb05 div           (normal)
.jssorb05 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
.jssorb05 .av           (active)
.jssorb05 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
.jssorb05 .dn           (mousedown)
*/
.jssorb05 {
position: absolute;
}
.jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
position: absolute;
/* size of bullet elment */
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background: url('../images/b05.png') no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}
.jssorb05 div { background-position: -7px -7px; }
.jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover { background-position: -37px -7px; }
.jssorb05 .av { background-position: -67px -7px; }
.jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover { background-position: -97px -7px; }

/* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 22 css */
/*
.jssora22l                  (normal)
.jssora22r                  (normal)
.jssora22l:hover            (normal mouseover)
.jssora22r:hover            (normal mouseover)
.jssora22l.jssora22ldn      (mousedown)
.jssora22r.jssora22rdn      (mousedown)
.jssora22l.jssora22lds      (disabled)
.jssora22r.jssora22rds      (disabled)
*/
.jssora22l, .jssora22r {
display: block;
position: absolute;
/* size of arrow element */
width: 40px;
height: 58px;
cursor: pointer;
background: url('../images/a22.png') center center no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
.jssora22l { background-position: -10px -31px; }
.jssora22r { background-position: -70px -31px; }
.jssora22l:hover { background-position: -130px -31px; }
.jssora22r:hover { background-position: -190px -31px; }
.jssora22l.jssora22ldn { background-position: -250px -31px; }
.jssora22r.jssora22rdn { background-position: -310px -31px; }
.jssora22l.jssora22lds { background-position: -10px -31px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
.jssora22r.jssora22rds { background-position: -70px -31px; opacity: .3; pointer- events: none; }

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
}
}



Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: Please share with us your code or better create a fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p9nu7r63/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use container-fluid instead of container.
The container is 1200px width, when you will use a bigger resolution on your desktop this will not be 80%.

if you want to override the behaviour of the .container for desktop or mobile only. you can use media queries.

You can also use bootstrap classes to hide certain content for other devices.

```
<div class="container visible-xs"> <!-- content for mobile only -->
```

I you want the desktop take 80% of the screen.

```
@media (min-width:1025px) { .container { width: 80% !important;} }
```

Comment: On mobile resolution `.container` and `.container-fluid` will behave the same. They have identical styles defined in `bootstrap.css`. On resolutions `sm` and higher they behave differently.

Comment: I dont get it really, I'm new to this all but how can i make it so the width on the desktop is 80% but on mobile 100% I changed my container to fluid (I had it fixed before)  but now is my slideshow out of place, Maybe you can provide me with some code?

Comment: This doesnt work,  It makes it not the full width but with a small line at both sides like this: http://prntscr.com/dcopvt This is on all devices. My slideshow i also out of place by this

Comment: Rainier, how about posting your code in a jsbin sample so i can make it work for you.

Comment: I addes a JSfiddle in a comment under the original post. but here it is again: jsfiddle.net/p9nu7r63

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129217/discussion-between-rainier-laan-and-mausinc).

Answer (score 0):

The better way to achieve your requirement is to use bootstrap offset classes. It will append an offset as specified width and resolution.

Here is a sample code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .parentcontainer {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .childcontainer {
            background: #000;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
        <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 parentcontainer">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 childcontainer">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

You can find more about offset classes [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-offsetting-columns).